# Focal function: How do I get the value of the center pixel and use this value within the focal fun argument?

Tags: r, r-raster

Example with a 3*3 neighborhood where the sum is multiplied with the center value "center".

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r[] <- 1:100
f<-function(x,center) {sum(x)*center}
r.f <- focal(r, w=matrix(1,3,3),fun=f}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carl's approach will work. It might be more efficient to do:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r[] <- 1:100
r.f <- focal(r, w=matrix(1,3,3)) * r
```

Comment: Should be faster than mine, as it looks to avoid having to calculate 100 sums and divides.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.  Since  the argument `fun` must accept multiple values, it may well be the case that you should use

```
f <-function(x) {
y = sum(x)/x[5]
return(y)
}
```

Because you're always feeding an `x` which is a 3x3 matrix, so the fifth element will be the center one.
No `R` on the machine I'm using to type this, so I can't verify :-(