# Calculate difference between raster cell and neighborhood

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I am trying to calculate the difference between a raster cell and the mean value in a 3 x 3 neighborhood.

With this raster

```
r = raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, xmn=0, xmx=100, ymn=0, ymx=100)
set.seed(123)
values(r) = round(runif(ncell(r),1,100))
```

I could use something similar to

```
r2 <- focal(r2, w=matrix(1,nrow=3,ncol=3), fun=)
```

but think I need a custom function as the argument to `fun` to calculate the mean value of the 3 x 3 neighborhood and then subtract the value from the center cell.

I know I could do this with two different raster layers but suspect there is an better way as outlined above.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890375/focal-function-how-do-i-get-the-value-of-the-center-pixel-and-use-this-value-wi/32900327#32900327

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in two steps:

```
#First, get the mean in a 3x3 neighbourhood
r2 <- focal(r, w=matrix(1,nrow=3,ncol=3), fun=mean)

#Then subtract the focal mean from the original cell values using simple raster arithmetic:
r3 <- r - r2
```

You can then easily wrap the above steps in a function it that's more convenient, cheers.

Comment: Thanks.  After running the code, the mean values were incorrect.  If 1/9 is the argument to `matrix`, then the `fun` needs to be `sum`  This code works as well `focal(r, w=matrix(1,nrow=3,ncol=3), fun=mean)` as mentioned here http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/1057_1f7e9ac569644689b7e4de78c1fece90.html

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, I did not think to check the code you posted originally too closely. See edit.